# How to setup SSL correctly on an erlang/ elixir server?

Tags: ssl, erlang, elixir

I have a valid Let's Encrypt SSL certificate which works as expected when setup on windows IIS:

https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://paperlesssolutionsltd.com.ng

[image]

When I apply same certificate to an [Elixir ACE](https://github.com/CrowdHailer/Ace#tlsssl) server like so:

```
certfile: Application.app_dir(@app, "priv/cert.pem"),
keyfile: Application.app_dir(@app, "priv/cert.key")
```

I get the following errors:

https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://paperlesssolutionsltd.com.ng:8443

[image]

Please what does Erlang SSL config require in order to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know much about SSL, but it would appear to me the certificate is being served fine by Elixir. Is it possible the SSL checker goes to check the cert chain and says "Let's Encrypt only signed for paperlesssolutionsltd.com.ng and not paperlesssolutionsltd.com.ng:8443"? I don't think ports are part of the spec, but I could see someone handling them that way. :shrug: That's the only difference I really see unless Elixir was only giving them part of the certificate, which I see as less likely.

Comment: @BrettBeatty  I have no idea... a 3rd party tried calling my server and they got errors because of the missing intermediate certs, or so they claimed. That is what led me to check this.

Comment: also i tested this on port 443, and had same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was an erlang issue!

Upgrading to `OTP 23.2.4` helped.

Also I had to use a cert file that combined my cert and Lets-encrypt's intermediate file.

Set this to both `:certfile` and `:cacertfile`

All credit to @voltone (Bram Verburg)

https://elixirforum.com/t/making-ssl-tests-all-pass-for-phoenix-lets-encrypt/3507/30?u=charleso